# solid and curve object fusion problem

Tags: tikz-pgf, 3d, pst-solides3d

I need to draw several times an custom object built by a fusion operation. The object composition involves a curve type object, getting a successful drawn after the first insertion. But try it to add a second one, a blank screen (I use a online latex editor) clear the entire picture. My suspicious coming from the curve object fusion but i'm not sure.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pst-solides3d}

\begin{document}
\begin{center}
\begin{pspicture}[showgrid=false](-0.5,-3.7)(8.5,6)
\psset{viewpoint=20 0 40 rtp2xyz,lightsrc=20 45 50 rtp2xyz,Decran=30}
\psset{solidmemory}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\dofAxis}[1]{
\def\r {2.5}
\psSolid[object = cone,
    h = 0.2,
    r = 0.07,
    RotX = 90,
    RotY = 45,
    RotZ = 85,
    fillcolor = black,
    grid = false,
    action = none,
    name = A](0,\r,0)
\defFunction[algebraic]{FIII}(t){\r*cos(t)}{\r*sin(t)}{0}
\psSolid [object = courbe,
      r = 0.01, 
      range = 1.55 6.6,
      linecolor = black,
      linewidth = 0.1,
      ngrid= 360 8,
      function = FIII,
      action = none,
      name = B]
\psSolid[ object = fusion,
    base =A B,
    action = draw**,        
    linewidth = 0.1, name =C](#1)%
}

\@namedef{p1}{ 0.00 0.00 0.00 }
\@namedef{p2}{ 2.00 -2.00 1.00 }
\dofAxis{\@nameuse{p1}}
%\dofAxis{\@nameuse{p2}}
\makeatother
\end{pspicture}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

This is a simplified code and contains a single function `\dofAxis{}` which is a rounded arrow formed by a tip (solid cone) and a body which is a partial circle drawn by the  `object=courbe`. After that, a fusion operation is performed to simplify and create a single object that it can be moved providing a 3d-coordinate point as a function's argument.
To call it, I provide a 3d-coordinate point, in a list, by the variable name `\@nameuse{p1}` in the macro `\dofAxis{\@nameuse{p1}}`.
The punctually use for this object is providing a customizable information for several axis (not related between them) contained in a bigger diagram. So for this purpose,  to simplify the object construction this approach using fusion operation was thought.

As always, any suggest is welcome received.

PS: The main objective is keeping the abstraction approach to draw parameterized fusioned objects using customizable arguments.
PS2: Add a second image to clarify the fusioned object.

[image: only one fusioned object can be plotted]
[image]

Comment: Thanks @marmot for the answer. I provide a simplified code, tikz is part of the main code. The fusion operation is made for joint several objects and move its as a single piece using a single argument in the macro `\dofAxis{}`.

Comment: Thanks @marmot for the answer. No, it's perfectly fine. The desired object is righlty drawn in both pictures. But when I tried to call the second code line `\dofAxis{\@nameuse{p2}}` the entire picture is cleared. This is a mistake. Even if you, unpack the macros code, write 2 times followed then the same behavior described above occurs.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification! Do you insist on the pstricks arrow head? (IMHO the shading is not as good as what one gets with asymptote, and if you do not care about the shading being realistic, you could also go with a pseudo-3D cone and a `tikz-3dplot` solution which will be *much* easier to compile. Notice, however, that I may be considered biased.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found an alternative solution. The problematic object `courbe` was replaced by a different object `object=surfaceparametree`, modifiying the 7.11.3. Example 2 in [pst-solides3d manual](http://mirrors.ctan.org/graphics/pstricks/contrib/pst-solides3d/doc/pst-solides3d-doc.pdf) (page 103).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pst-solides3d}
\begin{document}
\begin{center}
\begin{pspicture}[showgrid=false](-5.5,-3.7)(8.5,6)
\psset{viewpoint=20 45 45 rtp2xyz,lightsrc=20 45 50 rtp2xyz,Decran=30}
\psset{solidmemory}
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\dofAxis}[2]{

\defFunction{helix}(u,v)
    {2 .02 v Cos mul sub u Cos mul 0.3 mul}
    {2 .02 v Cos mul sub u Sin mul 0.3 mul}
    {.01 v Sin mul}

\psSolid[ object = surfaceparametree,
    linewidth = 0.5,
    base = -4.725 0 0 6.28,
    fillcolor = gray!80,
    incolor = gray!50,
    function = helix,
    action = none,
    ngrid = 60 0.4,
    name = A]%

\psSolid[object = cone,
    h = 0.25,
    r = 0.08,
    RotX = 90,
    RotY = 45,
    RotZ = 85,
    fillcolor = black!70, 
    linecolor = black!70,
    linewidth = 0.01,
    grid = false,
    action = draw,
    name = B](0,0.6,0)

\psSolid[ object = fusion,
    base = A B ,
    action = draw**,           
    grid = false,
    name = C, #2](#1)%
}
\@namedef{p1}{ 0.00 0.00 0.00 }
\@namedef{p2}{ 2.00 -2.00 1.00 }
\@namedef{p3}{ 2.00 -4.00 2.00 }
\dofAxis{\@nameuse{p1}}{}
\dofAxis{\@nameuse{p2}}{RotX = 90}
\dofAxis{\@nameuse{p3}}{RotY=90}
\makeatother
\end{pspicture}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

[image: simultaneous 3d curved arrows]